# How to change jQuery element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, var

The following script is working fine. Only, now I want to **add a more buttons** **and more ul class.** The script is only working with one button and one ul class.

I have tried so many things, but now I need help. Please see the picture below:

[image]

[The script (demo site)](http://radko.nl/question/)

```
<body>
        <header>
            Testing
        </header>

            <input type="button" value="Open 1" id="openOne" />
            <input type="button" value="Open 2" id="openTwo" />

    <ul class="imageDataOne clearfix">
        <li><a href="images/img-part-1-1.jpg" data-background-color="#000000"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/img-part-1-2.jpg" data-background-color="#000000"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="imageDataTwo clearfix">
        <li><a href="images/img-part-2-1.jpg" data-background-color="#000000"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/img-part-2-2.jpg" data-background-color="#000000"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //      v         Here is the problem                                 
            $('.imageDataOne a').apImageFullscreen({
                imageZoom:{},
            });

            $('#openOne').click(function() {
                $('.imageDataOne a:first')
                    .apImageFullscreen('option', 'enableScreenfull', $('#use-fullscreen').is(':checked'))
                    .apImageFullscreen('open', 0);
            });

            $('#openTwo').click(function() {
                $('.imageDataTwo a:first')
                    .apImageFullscreen('option', 'enableScreenfull', $('#use-fullscreen').is(':checked'))
                    .apImageFullscreen('open', 0);
            });             


        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain with more details what you are trying to do. Also put here complete code example from screenshot, or put it on jsfiddle so we can understand and solve

Comment: Sinisa Bobic, thanks for the advice. I'm tryng to do the best I can to explain how people can help.

Comment: Please read the "*[ask]*" guidelines. As it is your question is unclear, and posting additional, or clarifying questions, in images of your code is not helpful. In future bear in mind that we need your representative ("*[mcve]*") code *in* your question, not as an external resource.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, LEARNING java and how to ask a good question. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contents of the element using JQuery's [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('.imageData.clearfix').html(`<strong>This is the new element content</strong>`);
```

To append new data, use JQuery's [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content):

```
$('.imageData.clearfix').append(`<li><a href="images/pride-w'14-8_large.jpg" data-background-color="#000000"></a></li>`)
```

Comment: Miroslav, thank you for helping!! I have added an extra class and button. the second button wil not work right now.


// v Here is the problem
$('.imageDataOne a').apImageFullscreen({
imageZoom:{},
});

This has to open rigth now. so it works for button one. but now it has to open de second window in the same destignation. Here is where I am looking for a-the solution.

Comment: what part of it is not working, I need some more information, what have you tried?

Comment: $('.imageDataTwo a').apImageFullscreen({
                imageZoom:{},                                                                                                                           this is what I added to the script fot the second button to open, this is not working.

Comment: okay, so when you click(?) this `.imageDataTwo` what would you like to happen? I am trying to understand what the end result is here.

Comment: Yes, I understand it, great. I did try it to: it opens the screen but with conflicts. The pictures are not ordered and the inner buttons don't work.